# Why navigation.closeDrawer is not a function?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Dependencies version:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "~0.55.2",
    "react-navigation": "^2.0.1",
  }
```

I use `react-navigation` to navigate my screen, i create two screen and a drawer

Router.js:

```
import { createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import MainActivity from './components/MainActivity';
import ThisWeek from './components/ThisWeek';
import DrawerPanel from './components/DrawerPanel';

const Stack = createStackNavigator({
  MainActivity: {
    screen: MainActivity,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Welcome',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#81A3A7', 
        elevation: null
      }
    }
  },
  ThisWeek: {
    screen: ThisWeek
  }
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'MainActivity'
}
);

const Router = createDrawerNavigator({
    FirstScreen: {
      screen: Stack
    }
  },
  {
    contentComponent: DrawerPanel,
    drawerWidth: 200
  });

export default Router;
```

In my `DrawerPanel.js` i can click the two button navigate to the screen, but when i try to use `this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();` that shows an error `_this2.props.navigation.closeDrawer is not a function`.

So i try to `console.log(this.props);`,i can see `openDrawer` and  `closeDrawer` under `navigation`
[image]

Here is my DrawerPanel.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, FlatList, Text } from 'react-native';
import { View } from 'react-native-animatable';
import { List, Button } from 'react-native-elements';

class DrawerPanel extends Component {

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: '#81A3A7' }}>

        <Button
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.actions.closeDrawer();
            this.props.navigation.navigate('MainActivity');
          }}
          backgroundColor={'#81A3A7'}
          containerViewStyle={{ width: '100%', marginLeft: -61 }}
          title='Main page' 
        />
        <Button
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ThisWeek')}
          backgroundColor={'#81A3A7'}
          containerViewStyle={{ width: '100%', marginLeft: -46 }}
          title='This weel'
        /> 
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

export default DrawerPanel;
```

I can't figure it out why i can use `this.props.navigation.navigate();` to another screen not allow to use `this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();`

I try make a change to use `this.props.navigation.actions.closeDrawer();` the error will show `Cannot read property 'closeDrawer' of undefined`.

What step i make it wrong ? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this

```
import { DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation';

this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer());
this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
```

Comment: Now, `DrawerActions` should be imported from 'react-navigation-drawer'

Comment: Version 5: `import { DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native';`

Answer (score 5):

You are using both StackNavigator and DrawrNavigator so that the way to use them is different a little bit.

Keep in mind we have two version for react-navigation (v1 and v2) for now so that you should read the documentation carefully.

Please try using this:

- Close drawer

  `this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerClose');` // for version 1
  `this.props.navigation.openDrawer();`     // for version 2
- Open drawer:

  `this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen');`  // for version 1
  `this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();`       // for version 2

Be careful for reference any bugs fix for this libraries on the internet which you have to know which version is using in.

- Note that the order of nesting - if the stack navigator is not inside of the drawer, it will not have the openDrawer function.

  I guess it will work for you in this case.

Cheer!

Comment: Thanks for your help , i try it  but it's not working thoug there is no error.

Comment: Thanks. surprisingly, the accepted answer didn't work for me, but yours did... :)

Comment: i didnt get an error with the openDrawer and closeDrawer but when i click on the menu button in the header (which is responsible for opening drawer) then the drawer opens and closes by itself (more like a flash).

Comment: So what do you do in the case of the stack navigator not being inside the drawer?

Answer (score 0):

In your DrawerPanel file. You did not use the constructor. Hence, your component's props did not know about the navigation props that the DrawerNavigator passed in. Try putting this before your render function in the component.

```js
constructor(props){
  super(props);
}
```

This way you will no longer need to use dispatch(), but instead use openDrawer() and closeDrawer().